# How to Upload Video in database using C#.net in Visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have below code to upload video files into database  but when we upload video and click on upload button then my webpage go offline and data is not store into data base what happening I don't know.

my database table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVideos](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Video_Name] [varbinary](50) NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ContentType] [varbinary](50) NULL,
[Data] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

my aspx code

```
<table style="margin-left:150px; height:546px">
      <tr class="tr">
          <td colspan="3">
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                  Font-Size="15pt" ForeColor="#0099FF" Text="Add New Video"></asp:Label>
              &nbsp;<br />
              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" 
                Font-Size="7pt" Text="Make Sure Video in MP4 format"></asp:Label>
          </td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="tr">
       <td class="style1"> Video Name&nbsp; :</td>
       <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtideoname"  Height="24px" Width="270px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td>
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr">
       <td class="style1">Video type :</td>
       <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtvideotype"  Height="24px" Width="270px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td>
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="tr">
       <td  class="style1">video:</td>
       <td>
         <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /></td>
        <td>
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr">
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td><asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" Text="Upload" Width="132px" Height="34px" BackColor="Red" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" onclick="btnupload_Click"/><br />
           <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"/></td>
        <td>
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr">
          <td>
              &nbsp;</td>
          <td>
              &nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>



my C# Code
 using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblVideos(Video_Name,Name, ContentType, Data) values (@Video_Name,@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Video_Name", txtideoname.Text);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", "video/mp4");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code, are there any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: How large is the video file you are trying to upload? Have you checked the Event viewer in Windows to see if anything is logged there?

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem is that both `Video_Name` and `ContentType` are also being stored as `varbinary`, and don't seem to be cast in your SQL. Have you tried changed them to `varchar`?

Comment: Thanks frind for your answer and I Change  my code Video_Name,ContentType  from varbinary to varchar(50) and debug my code but my webpage go offline and show following errors  The connection was rese.
  .The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.        

 The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: Do you get the same error in other browsers, other than Firefox?

Comment: now it's working fine thanks again and i want code for display videos

Comment: I'd suggest opening another question for that, but you might want to start by checking out the HTML5 `video` tag. Older browser support is a little more complex.